# How to use java.net.URL/URLConnection with a proxy-chain

Tags: java, networking, web, proxy, tunneling

I try to load websites over a chain of proxies(more then one) with java.
Every Request should be able to use another chain.
Here my first quick and dirty try:

```
// My proxies and there ports marked with pIP1 pPort1, pIP2 pPort2...
Socket socket = new Socket(pIP1, pPort1);
OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

String connectOverProxy1ToProxy2 = "CONNECT " + pIP2 + ":" + pPort2 + " HTTP/1.1\n\n";
String connectHost = "GET http://stackoverflow.com/ HTTP/1.1\n\n";

out.write((connectOverProxy1ToProxy2 + connectHost).getBytes());
out.flush();

String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
  System.out.println(inputLine);

out.close();
in.close();
```

As response i recived this:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established
Proxy-agent: tinyproxy/1.8.3

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: public, max-age=30
Expires: Mon, 08 Apr 2013 11:42:08 GMT
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Date: Mon, 08 Apr 2013 11:41:36 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 08 Apr 2013 11:41:08 GMT
Vary: *
Content-Length: 182825

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
[..]
</html>
```

Lets come to the problem.
Now I try to load the page with URL/URLConnection to use the full handling and functinality of the java-packages. Is there a way to use URL/URLConnection with a chain of proxies instead a single proxy?

Thanks for the help...

Comment: The `HttpUrlConnection` class supports proxies by using the [proxy-related system settings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html#Proxies). I assume it doesn't matter whether there is just one proxy or multiple proxies, as long as you manage to configure the first one correctly.

Comment: Ok that should be working but I need the possibility to build a new chain for every request and many requests parallel. I fixed the question. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

The `HttpUrlConnection` class supports proxies by using the [proxy-related system settings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html#Proxies).

You can, however, change the default proxy selection mechanism by calling [ProxySelector.setDefault()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ProxySelector.html#setDefault%28java.net.ProxySelector%29) and supplying your own `ProxySelector` subclass.

By overriding the [`select(URL)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ProxySelector.html#select%28java.net.URI%29) method, you can return the desired proxy for that URL. I would first try to return just the 'first' proxy in the chain and see whether the `HttpUrlConnection` automatically makes its way through the proxy chain.

Comment: If i read it correct, the ProxySelectorClass hold a set of proxies and  return a sublist of it by executing "select(URI uri)" but how can i build and use a proxy-chain this way?

Comment: Setup a fix proxy-chain is'nt a solution for my problem. I did not have access to the proxy-setups. Lets say all my proxies are foreign-open-proxies. I have to build the complete proxy-chain with the request itself(or on the client-mashine). Hope i understand your advice correct.